# How to convert array of Transform to reorderablelist ? How to draw the items names instead "Element 0" "Element 1"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I use reorderablelist with this array of targets?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MultipleLookAtTargets : MonoBehaviour
{
    public FLookAnimator lookAnimator;
    public Transform[] targets;
    public bool lookAtSpecificTarget = false;
    public int lookAtSpecificTargetIndex;
    public float switchingTime;
    public bool switchingLoop = false;

    private bool loopOnce = true;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        if (lookAtSpecificTarget && targets.Length > 0)
        {
            if (lookAtSpecificTargetIndex >= 0)
            {
                lookAnimator.ObjectToFollow = targets[lookAtSpecificTargetIndex];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            StartCoroutine(SwitchTargetsPeriodically());
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {

    }

    IEnumerator SwitchTargetsPeriodically()
    {
        for (int i = 0; true; i = (i + 1) % targets.Length)
        {
            if (i <= targets.Length - 1 && switchingLoop)
            {
                loopOnce = true;

                lookAnimator.ObjectToFollow = targets[i];
            }

            if (switchingLoop == false && loopOnce)
            {
                if (i <= targets.Length - 1)
                {
                    lookAnimator.ObjectToFollow = targets[i];
                }

                if (i == (targets.Length - 1))
                {
                    loopOnce = false;
                }
            }

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(switchingTime);
        }
    }
}
```

The main goal is to select in the inspector a target item one or more by clicking on it in the inspector instead of typing the index number of the target as I did with the lookAtSpecificTargetIndex.

I want in the inspector instead the array to make a reorderablelist and instead "Element 0" "Element 1" it should draw "Target 1" "Target 2" and enable multi selection if, for example, I want to delete more than one item from the reorderablelist.

and last when selecting an item to highlight it with some color maybe some light blue.

Comment: This is actually quite a large order, with a lot of work behind it.  [Suggested Reading](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/property-drawers-and-custom-inspectors)

Comment: As @hijinxbassist mentioned this is done via custom editor scripting and can get quite complex! especially since you also want to implement some additional behavior that your current script itself doesn't even support yet ...